# Can titanium dioxide ($\rm TiO_2$) be used to block IR?

Tags: optics, material-science, optical-materials

I know that titanium oxide ($\rm TiO_2$) is mostly used to block UV lights, but can it be used for the blocking of near-infrared light?

If yes, then what are the principles behind it?

I would sincerely appreciate any help.

Comment: If you have the money and need, you can buy rutile (crystalline titanium dioxide) prisms from, e.g., Thorlabs: https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=ADT-6. I will bet they know about the IR transmittance of those prisms.

Answer (score 2):

No.  TiO$_2$ is an insulator with a [band gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_gap) of about 2.7 eV. This means that in order to excite the electrons in TiO$_2$ to higher-energy states, you need to provide an energy of at least 2.7 eV.

If you send a photon with sufficient energy into the crystal, it will quickly be absorbed by an electron and the energy it carried will be dispersed throughout the crystal in the form of lattice vibrations (i.e. heat).  On the other hand, if your photon has energy less than 2.7 eV, the electrons will not be able to absorb it and it will simply pass through the crystal largely unimpeded.

The UVA, UVB, and UVC regimes correspond to photons with energy between 3 and 12 eV.  These photons have enough energy to excite the electrons in TiO$_2$, which means they will not make it through the crystal.  This is why TiO$_2$ is *opaque* to such photons.  On the other hand, the infrared regime corresponds to photon energies between 1 meV and 1.7 eV.  They are insufficient to cause electronic excitations, so the crystal will be transparent to them.

Comment: Titanium dioxide is commonly used as the pigment in "white" paint: The finely divided powder diffusely reflects all visible wavelengths. Are you saying that it would look dark (i.e., it would absorb the light, rather than reflect it) if it was photographed by ultraviolet light?

Comment: @SolomonSlow Powder has very different optical characteristics than a pure crystal.  Crystalline silicon dioxide is quartz, and is transparent to visible light due to its band gap of nearly 6 eV.  However, it's powder form (sand, basically) appears to be opaque because light is scattered every time it enters or leaves a grain.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I meant that if you made a window out of crystalline TiO$_2$ and tried to photograph it with UV light, it would appear dark.  I'm not sufficiently well-versed in the optics of powders to be able to say what the powder form would look like under the same circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for your help. 
I read several research papers that used TiO2 to make a thin film to block IR. (https://www.gns.cri.nz/static/pubs/2013/SR%202013-039.pdf, https://doi.org/10.1117/12.312696)
I also saw a video (https://youtu.be/M0KfxXbq90I at 7:50) explaining how ITO blocks infrared light. Could this concept be applied to TiO2 as well? If not, what prevents it from doing so? @J.Murray

Comment: @JunwonLee Similarly to my comment directed toward Solomon, the optical properties of thin films and particulate pigments can be very interesting.  My answer refers to the bulk transparency/opacity of bulk crystalline TiO$_2$, not necessarily to the *reflectivity* of thin films and pigments.  As for your second question, ITO is a doped semiconducting alloy, which means the conduction band can absorb low energy excitations (IR in this case).  Crystalline TiO$_2$ is an insulator, not a semiconductor, meaning that it can only be excited by photons with energy greater than the band gap.

Answer (score 0):

In the UV region, TiO2 absorbs and scatters: providing very efficient blocking.
In the visible region TiO2 has little absorption but can scatter very efficiently.  So , it is also capable of strong blocking of visible radiation (Otherwise it wouldn't be the pigment of choice in white paints, inks and plastics). I use 'can' because the efficiency depends on the particle size of the TiO2. A crude rule of thumb is that size of the TiO2 should be ~50% of the wavelength of radiation to be scattered. This is also true in the near (solar) infrared where larger crystal TiO2 pigments (0.40-1.00microns c.f. 0.25 micron for the visible region)) are used. TiO2 absorbs/emits efficiently in the mid-IR, so I suppose it functions as a blocker in that region too.